Homotopy equivalence between any Topological spaces.
I am beginning my studies in the area of homotopy theory, and I am studying from the book "Fundamental Group and Covering Spaces" by the Brazilian author Elon Lages Lima.
As this is my first contact, I am trying to understand all the implicit details of the subject.
Let's establish some concepts and notations:

Let $X, Y$ be topological spaces, a continuous map $f\colon X\longrightarrow Y$ is called a homotopy equivalence when there exists a continuous map $g\colon Y\longrightarrow X$ such that $g\circ f \simeq id_X$ and $f\circ g\simeq id_Y$, where $id$ denotes the identity map. In this case, we say that $g$ is the homotopy inverse of $f$ and that the topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ have the same homotopy type, and we denote this by $X\equiv Y$.


Let's denote by $[X,Y]=\lbrace[f]\,|\,f\colon X\longrightarrow Y\rbrace$, that is, the set of homotopy classes of continuous maps from $X$ to $Y$.


Remark 1: I already know that the homotopy relation is an equivalence, and that the operation $[f]\circ[g]=[f\circ g]$ is well defined.


Remark 2: I also know that homotopy is invariant under composition of maps.

I am trying to prove the following: If $X\equiv X'$ and $Y\equiv Y'$, then $[X,Y]$ and $[X',Y']$ have the same cardinality.
What I have so far: By hypothesis, I know that there exist continuous maps $\varphi\colon X\longrightarrow X'$, $\varphi^*\colon X'\longrightarrow X$ such that $\varphi\circ\varphi^* \simeq id_{X'}$ and $\varphi^*\circ\varphi\simeq id_{X}$; and there also exist continuous maps $\psi\colon Y\longrightarrow Y'$, $\psi^*\colon Y'\longrightarrow Y$ such that $\psi\circ\psi^* \simeq id_{Y'}$ and $\psi^*\circ\psi\simeq id_Y$.
We can define $F\colon[X,Y]\longrightarrow[X',Y']$ given by $F([f]) = [\psi\circ f\circ \varphi]$. What needs to be done then is to show that $F$ is a bijective function. But first it would be important to prove that $F$ is well defined. In fact, by Remark 1, I already know that there is independence from the choice of the class representative, so it remains to prove that $[\psi\circ f\circ\varphi]\in[X',Y']$, right? In other words, I would need to prove that $[\psi\circ f\circ\varphi]$ is a homotopy class between $X'$ and $Y'$. In fact, what I know is that $\varphi$ is a map between $X$ and $X'$, $\psi$ is a map between $Y$ and $Y'$, $f$ is a map between $X$ and $Y$, but I am having difficulty manipulating these objects, and I am not making any progress. Could someone give me a hand?

Your map $F$ is not properly defined (you cannot compose $\varphi : X \to X'$ and $f : X \to Y$).
The correct version is
$$F([f]) = [\psi] \circ [f] \circ [\varphi^*].$$
$F$ is well-defined. $F$ depends on the choice of $\varphi$ and $\psi$, but that is irrelevant here.
Also the function
$$G : [X',Y'] \to [X,Y], G([f']) = [\psi^*] \circ [f'] \circ [\varphi]$$
is well-defined. We have
$$(G \circ F) ([f]) = G(F([f])) = G([\psi] \circ [f] \circ [\varphi^*]) = [\psi^*] \circ [\psi] \circ [f] \circ [\varphi^*] \circ [\varphi] \\
= [\psi^* \circ \psi] \circ [f] \circ [\varphi^* \circ \varphi] = [id_Y] \circ [f] \circ [id_X] = [id_Y \circ f \circ id_X] =[f],$$
that is $G \circ F = id$. Similarly we can show $F \circ G = id$.
This means that $F$ is a bijection with inverse $F^{-1} = G$.

Ok, it is clear to me that $\psi\circ f \circ\varphi^$ is a continuous map. But why is it not necessary to check that $[\psi \circ f \circ \varphi^]$ is indeed a homotopy class? Does this follow from the fact that $[\psi] \circ [f] \circ [\varphi^*]$ is a well-defined homotopy class? Also, if $f \colon X \to Y$ is any continuous map, can I always assume that $f$ belongs to some homotopy class?


You can compose homotopy classes (Remark 1). 2 . Writing $[\alpha]$ means that it is the homotopy class of the map $\alpha$, there is nothing to check. 3. By Remark 1 you have $[\psi] \circ [f] \circ [\varphi^] = [\psi \circ f  \circ \varphi^]$, but it is unneccessary to use this equation when defining $F$. 4. Each map $f : X \to Y$ belongs by definition to the homotopy class $[f]$.


Thanks for your help!

$F$ is well-defined if $[f] = [g]$ implies $F([f]) = F([g])$, that is if $f \sim g$ implies $\psi \circ f \circ \varphi \sim \psi \circ g \circ \varphi$, which you seem to already know (remark 2).
You don't need to prove that $[\psi \circ f \circ \varphi]$ is a homotopy class: it is by definition the homotopy class of $\psi \circ f \circ \varphi$.

I know that $\psi \circ f \circ \varphi^*$ is a continuous function, but I cannot see yet why it follows from the definition. If $f \colon X \to Y$ is any continuous function, can I always assume that $f$ belongs to some homotopy class?

$f$ always belongs to $f$'s homotopy class, by definition of what a homotopy class is. (Or more generally an equivalence class.)

Thanks for your help!
